# Dynamic Strong params for require - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, strong-parameters

I have an update method right now that will not work for all situations. It is hard coded in the strong params like this `params.require(:integration_webhook).permit(:filters)` that all fine right now but sometimes it may be `integration_webhook` and other times it needs to be `integration_slack`. Basically, is there a way that I don't need to hardcode the require in the strong params? I'll show my code for clarity.

### Update Method:

```
    def update
     @integration = current_account.integrations.find(params[:id])

     attrs = params.require(:integration_webhook).permit(:filters)

     if @integration.update_attributes(attrs)
      flash[:success] = "Filters added"
      redirect_to account_integrations_path
     else
      render :filters
     end
   end
```

As you can see it's a standard update method. But I need the integration_webhook params to be dynamic. I'm wondering if there is a model method I could call to strip away the integration_webhook part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally sure how dynamic this needs to be, but assuming that we are either getting an `integratino_webhook` or a `integration_slack`.

```
def update
  @integration = current_account.integrations.find(params[:id])

  if @integration.update_attributes(update_params)
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end

private
  def update_params
    params.require(:integration_webhook).permit(:filters) if params.has_key?(:integration_webhook)
    params.require(:integration_slack).permit(:filters) if params.has_key?(:integration_slack)
  end
```

Checkout [Strong parameters require multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487878/strong-parameters-require-multiple) if this didn't answer your question.

## Edit

For more dynamic requiring:

```
def update_params
  [:integration_webhook, :integration_slack].each do |model|
    return params.require(model).permit(:filters) if params.has_key?(model)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm.. That's interesting. That could work. I have three integrations right now and it could continue to grow. But that's seems like a decent solutions. Thanks

Comment: should this be a private method?

Comment: I'll modify the answer for more dynamic goodness and yes, this should not turn into a `ActionController::Base` action.

Comment: This won't work because it still try's to run integration_webhook which will raise `param is missing or the value is empty: integration_webhook`.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: how do I call that in my update method? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Just `@integration.update_attributes(update_params)`, no?

Comment: I tried that and I got this error `When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122632/discussion-between-fbelanger-and-cameron-bass).

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of  my head something like this should work.  The naming convention isn't the best but it the structure will allow you to just add to the list if you need to.

```
def update
     @integration = current_account.integrations.find(params[:id])

     if @integration.update_attributes(webhook_and_slack_params)
      flash[:success] = "Filters added"
      redirect_to account_integrations_path
     else
      render :filters
     end
   end


def webhook_and_slack_params
  [:integration_webhook, :integration_slack].each do |the_params|
  if(params.has_key?(the_params))
   params.require(the_params).permit(:filters)
  end
end
```